# IdentityServer4 token issuer in docker-compose enviroment

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm tring to containerize my asp.net application based on microservice architecture. Fronted part of my app represented as React SPA. Here is content of my `docker-compose.yml` (services section)

```
    services:
      consul:
        image: consul
        ports:
          - "8500:8500"
          - "8600:8600"
          - "8600:8600/udp"
        entrypoint: consul agent -dev -client=0.0.0.0
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        expose:
          - "5432"
        environment:
          - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345678"  
      identity:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: src/IdentityServer/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "5000:5000"
        environment:    
          - SelfUrl=http://identity:5000
          - consul:Address=http://consul:8500
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
          - ASPNETCORE_URLS http://identity:5000
        depends_on:
          - consul
          - postgres
      apigateway:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: src/apigateway/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "5001:5001"
        environment:
          - SelfUrl=http://apigateway:5001
          - AllowedClientUrl=http://localhost:5003
          - IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions:Authority=http://identity:5000
          - consul:Address=http://consul:8500
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        depends_on:
          - consul
          - postgres
          - identity
      taskservice:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: src/taskservice/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "5016:5016"
        environment:
          - SelfUrl=http://taskservice:5016
          - AllowedClientUrl=http://localhost:5003
          - IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions:Authority=http://identity:5000
          - consul:Address=http://consul:8500
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        depends_on:
          - consul
          - postgres
          - identity
          - apigateway
```

When I `docker-compose up` and simultaneously start my SPA in development mode it sends the request to `localhost:5000` to authorize the user. SPA successfuly retrives token and accroding to this token it's issuer is `http://localhost:5000` (as far as I know this comes from the `Host` header in HTTP request).

The next request (includes recieved token) from my SPA goes to `apigateway` service, and this causes an error `Issuer is invalid` since it expects to be `http://identity:5000` accroding to `IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions:Authority=http://identity:5000`.

According to IdentityServer4 documentation `IdentityServer Option` provides `IssuerUri` parameter which help to resolve my issue but using of this parameter is not reccomended in production.

I thought that nginx reverse-proxy could help to resolve this issue by changing `Host` header to `identity:5000` but this makes idenity service to redirect to `http://identity:5000` to issue the token and causes an error because `http://identity` is inside container only.

Is there any other approach to implement token issuing inside containerized identity server with issuer that be valid in other container environment?

Comment: I think it boils down to the fact that all relying parties should access the IDP using the same host name. In the real world it'll need a proper domain and certificate anyway.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this. It is exactly the issue that is described in the above comment. I've managed to get mine to work with a small workaround, but it's not completely functional. If I call the connect/token endpoint directly, I can get a valid bearer token, and I can use that to access my API in another container. But we use swagger ui with our API and it has 'built in' oauth support, which isn't able to access the IDP as it's popping up a browser on my local machine looking for the docker-compose bridge network address, which I cant access (can't seem to even use hosts)